# Running dotnet in a Docker container fails on Linux because of relative path

Tags: .net, docker, .net-5, dotnet-sdk

I have a Dockerfile that builds and publishes an application to a container like this

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 as builder
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish Project -c Release -o ./publish

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0 as runner
COPY --from=builder  /publish .
WORKDIR data
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "../Project.dll"]
```

Building the image and running the container works on Windows, but does not work on Ubuntu server.

```
project_1  | Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly '/Project.dll'. The system cannot find the file specified.
project_1  |
project_1  | File name: '/Project.dll'
```

I think the problem is in specifying the argument for `dotnet` as `../Project.dll`, because the shell expands this to `/Project.dll` and dotnet does not understand Linux paths. Is there a way to fix this?

I'm a beginner to Docker, maybe I'm missing something (shouldn't Docker work the same on every platform?)

EDIT: running `dotnet Project.dll` from bash in the container inside the parent directory produces the same exact output

Comment: There is no shell involved here.  If you look inside the built image (change `ENTRYPOINT` to `CMD`, then `docker run --rm -it your-image sh`) is the file there?

Comment: you aren't doing an absolute path here, you're doing a relative one in ENTRYPOINT.  title needs to be corrected.

Comment: @DavidMaze yes, the file is there

Comment: @DavidMaze running `dotnet ../Project.dll` from sh produces the same exception, although I can see the file ../Project.dll using ls from sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be a permission problem, and the application must be in a subfolder (not in the root folder), see https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish Project -c Release -o ./publish

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0 as runner
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder  /app/publish .
WORKDIR /app/data
CMD ../Project
```

Comment: good to know, thanks for posting the issue and resolution.